# What is the nature of a demiplane's walls?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, planes, wall

The [demiplane](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/demiplane) spell creates a demiplane that appears to be an empty room 30 feet in each dimension, **made of wood or stone**.

Are these walls actually made from wood and stone? Can a character chip off a piece of stone? A sliver of wood? Would it be possible to hide in them using the [meld into stone](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/meld-into-stone) spell if they are of stone?

Comment: Great questions, but I don’t think there are any answers. Even looking back to previous editions is no use, since *demiplane* is different from the methods of creating a demiplane in the past.

Comment: I count five questions in this question, maybe some cleanup and focus is in order.

Comment: Hi @Novak, I’ll take off the Passwall, its less related to it being Stone.

Comment: @Novak No, they're all aspects of one question, the one in the title: What's the nature of the wall?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Demiplane doesn't *have* walls in conventional sense. It just ends, looking like a wall to an observer (or like something else, according to the nature of specific demiplane).

According to Player's Handbook:

> Demiplanes are small extradimensional spaces with their own unique rules.

> A given demiplane can be entered through a single point where it touches another plane.

So, other than the door, it's not touching any other dimension. There is *absolutely nothing* through the "wall" of demiplane. No other plane, no space, no vacuum, nothing.

So the "material" of a demiplane, created specifically by Demiplane spell, is just an aspect of it, shaped by the spell (presumably for caster's convenience and sanity). It has no actual matter or thickness to it and doesn't separate demiplane from anything, since there is nothing on the other side. There is no other side altogether.

Comment: This answer could be improved by citing supporting material from the spell you reference. You're headed in the right direction, just needs a little bit of fine tuning!

Comment: @aaron9eee D&D 5e seems to be rather slim on mechanics of demiplanes. :) I think the PHB quotes I provided are basis for the interpretation that there is nothing demiplane borders (and if so it has no wall to separate it from anything).

Comment: I like this answer. Especially the highlight that the "wall" is part of the demiplane without thickness or matter. Yes, the books do not elaborate on it, but other options (like it being made of stone, or of magic) only lead to more problems or questions.

Answer (score 8):

### They are made of magic

As stated in the description:

> When opened, the door leads to a demiplane that **appears** to be an empty room 30 feet in each dimension, made of wood or stone.

The whole thing is a facade. It just looks like a room constructed of wood or stone. So you can't use any spells on/against the walls that require actual wood or actual stone.

Comment: If they are made of magic, what happens if you cast Antimagic Field in the Demiplane (say, after the spell duration expired and you are trapped there)?

Comment: @GroodytheHobgoblin, that would make a good separate question.

Comment: Asked about that alongside the case of *Dispel magic* in [this question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/200419/77044).

Answer (score 4):

### Probably not

The *Demiplane* spell’s description states:

> (…)demiplane that **appears to be** an empty room 30 feet in each dimension, made of wood or stone.(…)

*Appears to be* meaning that it’s not *really* a room with wood or stone walls, it just *looks* like one. Since the spell only mentions appearance, I think it’s reasonable to assume that the walls **only** *look* like they’re made of stone, they don’t actually *behave* like stone walls (since you know, the spells-only-do-what-they-say-they-do thing).
You probably then cannot either hide in them or chip anything off.

As to what exactly they’re made of and how they behave, I’m afraid there isn’t a lot of information. The walls are the boundaries of the demiplane that the spell creates but there’s not a whole lot of info on demiplanes in 5E, the only mention I found was in DMG, p.68 and all it says that might be relevant is that demiplanes are extradimensional spaces and can be as small as a single chamber. The whole demiplane is made of magic, so the boundaries probably are too but that’s as much as you can definitely state.